# Check function name exists and call by String

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to facilitate and organize my work between socket communication and Node.JS (My project is too big)

Instead of socket.emit() function in client-side I use a function that I created:

```
function socketEmit(socketName, functionName, data){
    socket.emit(socketName, {functionName: functionName, data: data});
}
socketEmit('exampleClass', 'exampleFunction', 'test');
socketEmit('exampleClass2', 'exampleFunction2', 'test');
```

After emit, I get the socket (socket.on) on the server-side with this function. And register it in the class depending on the "socketName"

```
socket.on('exampleClass', function (socketData){
        var exampleClass = require('./server/exampleClass.js');
        exampleClass.registerSocket(socket, socketData);
})
socket.on('exampleClass2', function (socketData){
        var exampleClass2 = require('./server/exampleClass2.js');
        exampleClass2.registerSocket(socket, socketData);
})
```

Within the classes has this function "registerSocket" to perform the same

**exampleClass.js**

```
module.exports = {
    registerSocket: function(socket, socketData){
        var functionName = socketData.functionName;
        var data = socketData.data;
        [functionName](socket, data);
    },
}

function exampleFunction(socket, data){
  console.log('test');
}
```

However, I have an error in this part in registerSocket function:

```
[functionName] is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call a an array `[functionName](socket, data);`:

```
const array = [functionName]; // array
array(socket, data); // you can't :)
```

Put the functions in an object, and access it using `[]` notation.

```
const fns = {
  exampleFunction(socket, data){
     console.log('test');
  }
};

module.exports = {
    registerSocket: function(socket, socketData){
        var functionName = socketData.functionName;
        var data = socketData.data;
        fns[functionName](socket, data);
    },
}
```